# Compute an $n\times n$ determinant with factorial and powers of $x$

Tags: matrices, determinant

Compute
$$
D_{n}=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 1\\
1 & 1! & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & x\\
1 & 2 & 2! & 0 & 0 & \ldots & x^{2}\\
1 & 3 & 3\cdot2 & 3! & 0 & \ldots & x^{3}\\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ddots & \ldots\\
1 & n & n\left(  n-1\right)   & n\left(  n-1\right)  \left(  n-2\right)   &
n\left(  n-1\right)  \left(  n-2\right)  \left(  n-3\right)   & \ldots & x^{n}%
\end{vmatrix}
$$

My attempt: I tried to make an expansion along the first row, but I didn't
obtain anything; I also tried to compute some particular cases by I didn't see
how to obtain a general formula such that to be capable to compute $D_{n}$.
Any ideeas?

Comment: so position $n+1,n$ has $n!$     ?

Comment: Why it's not marked as 'hint'? Indeed by expansion along then 2nd from the right column we get $D_n=-n!D_{n-1}$ or am I wrong?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin So there is no $x$ dependence?

Comment: @Will Jagy I think that the matrix from the above determinant has the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0_{n-1} & 1\\
1_{n-1} & A_{n} & ..\\
1 & B_{n} & x^{n}
\end{pmatrix}
,
$$
where $A_{n}=
\begin{vmatrix}
1! & 0 & .. & 0\\
2 & 2! & .. & 0\\
.. & .. & .. & 0\\
n-1 & \left(  n-1\right)  \left(  n-2\right)   & .. & \left(  n-1\right)  !
\end{vmatrix}
$ and $B_{n}=
\begin{pmatrix}
n & n\left(  n-1\right)   & \ldots & n\cdot\ldots\cdot2
\end{pmatrix}
.$

Comment: I had a mistake before.  Computer experiment through $n=10$ suggests $D_n=p_n(x-1)^n$ where $p_n=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}k!$  Earlier I had the upper index on the product as $n$ instead of $n-1$

Comment: @saulspatz As yes, ok. I was puzzling over this for a while but now I think I have a solution.

Comment: @paulinho Good, I've been getting nowhere.  I look forward to reading your solution, but I think I've fried my brain.  It will have to wait until tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $M_n$ be the matrix of interest (the argument of the determinant in your question). We claim that 
$$M_n = A_n B_n, ~ A_n = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 1 & 1! & 0 & \cdots 
 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 2! & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 1 & n & n(n - 1) & \cdots & n! \end{bmatrix}, ~ B_n = \begin{bmatrix} I_n & \vec{v}_{n-1} \\ 0 & (x - 1)^n / n!\end{bmatrix}$$
where $\vec{v}_{n-1}^T = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & x - 1 & (x - 1)^2 / 2 & \cdots & (x - 1)^{n-1} / (n-1)!\end{bmatrix}$. The correctness of the first $n$ columns of the product are trivial to verify. To verify the correctness of the last column, note that 
$$(A_n B_n)_{i, ~n+1} = \sum_{j = 0}^{i - 1} \frac{(i - 1)!}{(i - j - 1)!} \frac{(x - 1)^j}{j!} = \sum_{j = 0}^{i - 1} {i - 1 \choose j} (x - 1)^j = x^{i - 1}$$
by the Binomial Theorem. (Note here that the indexing of the matrix starts with   $1$, not zero.) As determinants are multiplicative, it follows that
$$\det(M_n) = \det(A_n) \cdot \det(B_n) = \left[ \prod_{k = 0}^n k! \right] \cdot (x - 1)^n / n! = \left[ \prod_{k = 0}^{n-1} k! \right] \cdot (x - 1)^n$$
since $\det(A_n)$ is simply the product of its diagonal entries (it's lower triangular) and $\det(B_n) = (x - 1)^n / n!$ by Laplace expanding along the last row. It's reassuring to see that this calculation confirms saulspatz's computer simulations. $\square$

Comment: Excellent.  I was messing around trying to do Laplace expansion on the next-to-last column, where there are only two nonzero entries, and trying to find a formula for the cofactors.  Is there something concrete that gave you the idea of factoring the matrix?

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks - I noticed it was nearly upper triangular except for the last column, and also noticed that by choosing $A_n$ as is, $B_n$’s left $n$ columns would be $I_n$ with a row of zeroes below it, making for two matrices whose determinant are easy to calculate. It was kinda lucky!